# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException' with message 'ob_end_clean()

Tags: fuelphp

Got this problem, please help me how to resolve it.  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException' with message 'ob_end_clean() [ref.outcontrol]: failed to delete buffer zlib output compression' in /public_html/dev/fuel/core/classes/error.php:177 Stack trace: #0 /public_html/dev/fuel/core/bootstrap.php(79): Fuel\Core\Error::error_handler(8, 'ob_end_clean() ...', '/...', 177) #1 [internal function]: {closure}(8, 'ob_end_clean() ...', '//...', 177, Array) #2 /public_html/dev/fuel/core/classes/error.php(177): ob_end_clean() #3 /public_html/dev/fuel/core/classes/error.php(92): Fuel\Core\Error::show_php_error(Object(ErrorException)) #4 /public_html/dev/fuel/core/bootstrap.php(63): Fuel\Core\Error::shutdown_handler() #5 [internal function]: {closure}() #6 {main} thrown in 
/public_html/dev/fuel/core/classes/error.php on line 177

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming due to zlib compression being enabled in the server/site. You can get rid of this error using the below line above ob_end_clean() on the causing file. Which in your case is error.php

Code should be look like this after the modification

```
    if($ob_get_status['name']!='zlib output compression')
    ob_end_clean();
```

For further read on the cause and more solutions you can visit this link 
[http://blog.waqasjamal.com/2014/07/how-to-solve-fatal-error-uncaught.html ]